# Comparing mutiple columns and selecting only one

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

My table is created like this:

```
CREATE TABLE Employees (
   EmployeeID char(4) PRIMARY KEY,
   EmployeeName varchar(30) NOT NULL,
   HourlyRate real,
   SkillType varchar(20),
   SupervisorID char(4) NOT NULL
 )
```

Insert statements:

```
insert into Employees values ('1235', 'J. Smith', 12.5, 'electrical', '1311')
insert into Employees values ('1412', 'A. Green', 13.75, 'plumbing', '1520')
insert into Employees values ('2920', 'J. Brown', 10.0, 'roofing', '2920')
insert into Employees values ('3231', 'A. Purple', 17.4, 'carpenter', '3231')
insert into Employees values ('1520', 'J. Red', 11.75, 'plumbing', '1520')
insert into Employees values ('1311', 'A. Orange', 15.5, 'electrical', '1311')
insert into Employees values ('3001', 'A. Black', 8.2, 'carpenter', '3231')
```

What I have is a table that lists employees and their Supervisor's ID, who are also contained in the same `Employees` table. I want to only select the employees that have a hourly rate higher than their corresponding supervisor.

I've tried lots of different `Select` statements to try this, but they either all return too many values, or no values at all. I know that I need to have 2 instances of the `Employee` table in order to compare the supervisors hourly rate with the employees hourly rate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this query. Notice that you will get only employees which have supervisor in the table. You want also them which hasn't supervisor you can use `LEFT JOIN` instead.

```
SELECT
   E1.*
FROM Employees E1
 JOIN Employees E2
   ON E1.SupervisorID = E2.EmployeeID
WHERE E1.HourlyRate > E2.HourlyRate
```